# Dagger 2: Missing Provider when both parent and child have same inject singnature?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger 2.24. When I compile the below

```
fun main() {
    val myClass = MyClass()
}

class MyClass {
    @Inject
    lateinit var stringMe: String

    init {
        DaggerMyComponent.create().subComponent().inject(this)
        println(stringMe)
    }
}

@Component
interface MyComponent {
    fun subComponent(): MySubcomponent
    fun inject(a: MyClass)
}

@Subcomponent(modules = [MeSubModule::class])
interface MySubcomponent {
    fun inject(a: MyClass)
}

@Module
class MeSubModule {
    @Provides
    fun stringMe(): String = "Hi here"
}
```

It error out stating

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface MyComponent {
                ^
  A binding with matching key exists in component: com.elyeproj.modular1bottombase.MySubcomponent
      java.lang.String is injected at
          com.elyeproj.modular1bottombase.MyClass.stringMe
      com.elyeproj.modular1bottombase.MyClass is injected at
          com.elyeproj.modular1bottombase.MyComponent.inject(com.elyeproj.modular1bottombase.MyClass)
```

Then I comment out the simple line below, all compile fine.

```
fun main() {
    val myClass = MyClass()
}

class MyClass {
    @Inject
    lateinit var stringMe: String

    init {
        DaggerMyComponent.create().subComponent().inject(this)
        println(stringMe)
    }
}

@Component
interface MyComponent {
    fun subComponent(): MySubcomponent
//    fun inject(a: MyClass)  // Comment this out.
}

@Subcomponent(modules = [MeSubModule::class])
interface MySubcomponent {
    fun inject(a: MyClass)
}

@Module
class MeSubModule {
    @Provides
    fun stringMe(): String = "Hi here"
}
```

Suspect it's a Dagger 2 bug, but just write here in case I miss anything?

Comment: Filed issue on Dagger 2 at the same time https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, as long as we have `inject(a: MyClass)` in `MyComponent` as below, at compile time, it will try to verify that `MyComponent` are able to satisfied all the `@Inject` dependencies that `MyClass` need.

```
@Component
interface MyComponent {
    fun subComponent(): MySubcomponent
    fun inject(a: MyClass)  // Comment this out.
}
```

In my case above, `MyClass` needs `String`, but `MyComponent` itself doesn't have the capability to provide the `String`. So it fails. The current annotation compilation does the check, and doesn't matter if there's actually *wired up* or not.